# 404 when fetching image from wp-content/uploads/

Tags: 404-error, mod-rewrite

I get 404 status when fetching images, and the http still contains that image. Image shows up in a browser, but the 404 code breaks some applications.

calls to wp-content/uploads/ are redirected in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?getfile=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Why do I get a 404 status if the image is in there and is served?

Comment: 1) What are you "getting" the image from, i.e., what user agent, what computer, etc.?
2) What plugins are active? Do you have a hotlinking protection plugin in place?

Comment: I'm getting it with a flash application (crossdomain settings ok) and with a simple wget command. Also firefox shows image, but firebug console states it's a 404 response. It's nice of him to load it anyway. And I have no such plugni in place, and site is set to be visible to search agents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved.

The plugin "User Access Manager" was found guilty of inserting a .htaccess file into `wp-content/uploads/` and not handling calls properly afterwards.

I don't know how UAM plugin could be fixed, but It's ok to remove the .htaccess file. Nothing else depends on it. (at least in my case)

Comment: 11 years later, same issue, same plugin

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your WordPress root directory and rename .htaccess to something like .htaccess_old. Next, login to your WordPress admin area and navigate to **Settings -> Permalinks**
Next, choose a different permalinks structure from what you currently have and click the **Save Changes** button. Next, select the original permalinks structure you had and click the **Save Changes** button once more. Note, this will create a new .htacess file in your server. Fixes the images returning the 404 error. Cheers!